# How to include ember addon's scss files directly into consuming app

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

**TL;DR**

How to import `scss` files from ember addon to consumers app(should import scss files and not processed `css` file, `scss` should be processed in consumer's app instead).

**Details:**

I am developing an addon and I am using sass for design, I want to let my users configure css properties from addon. For this I want to import `scss` files directly into the consumers app(I don't want them to use already compiled to css file that would go to `vendor.css` file) and override some of the variable's value.

**Here is the plan on how it should work:**

I have a configuration `scss` file, which has several variables I want to be configurable, user can override these variables by first including their own configuration `scss` file and our `scss` file below that([more details on how scss variables can be made overridable and are overriden](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-default)).

The file structure for `addon/styles` is as follows:

[image]

I have imported all css files inside addon.scss as follows:

```
@import 'config';
@import 'helpers';
@import 'normalize';
@import 'base';
@import 'utilities';
@import 'modules';
@import 'datetime-picker';
@import 'fontawesome';
@import 'animation';
@import 'states';
```

The values I want my user to override are in `_config.scss`. Part of my `_config.scss` file looks like this:

```
$header-font: $font-sans !default;
$header-font-size: $small-font-size !default;
$header-font-type: normal !default;
```

I want user to provide their own value for variables like `$header-font`,`$header-font-size` and include before `scss` from my addon is included.

Ember version: `1.13.3`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?